# Is it possible to bring to javascript the .net RBTree and its TreePage

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, red-black-tree

I've seen the [.NET RbTree](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/System/Data/RbTree.cs.html) work and I like it, much so that I've tried to bring it to Javascript. Then I realized it uses structs array (something very hard to emulate due to javascript's functionalities doesn't allow it, at least natively). Then I saw TreePage class which allows allocate slots maps for each tree page, all of this performed by bitwise shifts to achieve indexation (**RBTree.PageTable[index>>16].Slots[index&0xFFFF]**) and I know if is the same performance of .net. It's the only indexable-tree I've ever seen (the far I know and I could understand).

Now my question: Is it possible to bring that tree to Javascript> (I've seen [some](https://github.com/vadimg/js_bintrees/blob/master/lib/rbtree.js) examples but no one has indexation method). I hope to be understood, to get some answers and as I always say: Thanks in advance.

PD: Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it easy?  No.  Why don't you use an existing red-black tree JavaScript library?

Comment: Indexability. It's all I want. Like I said, I've not seen a single one capable of such feature.